# Injectivity of a vector-valued function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \Bbb{R}^2$ be defined as

$f(r,\theta) = (rcos\theta,rsin\theta)$

Then I need to tell for what values of $x$ and $y$, $f$ has an inverse.

I have checked by definition that $f$ is onto.

I needed to check its injectivity.

I formed the matrix of derivative and saw that $f$ will be one-one in a neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ if $(x,y)$ is not equal to $(0,0)$.

Can I deduce anything from here?

Comment: Note that $f(r, \theta) = f(r, \theta +2\pi)$. Also, try to prove that $f$ is bijective when it is restricted to $\mathbb{R} \times [0, 2\pi)$

Comment: You should only consider positive reals @cos_dm_math21

Comment: @nicomezi Of course. Thank you!

Comment: Why positive reals?

Comment: Why will this restriction be onto?